# How to launch an .exe file by clicking a JButton in GUI?

Tags: java, exe, jbutton, actionlistener

I've created a JFrame with 3 Jbuttons. I'd like the button to launch different .exe file located in the same folder. Is this possible? If yes, what should i write for the actionListener? On the other hand, instead of launching an exe file, is it possible to launch a main class using a JButton? If yes, what should i write for the actionListener?

Note: The .exe file is created from a java main program.

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Program1"); //The JButton name.
frame.add(button1); //Add the button to the JFrame.
button1.addActionListener().... // how to launch the .exe file
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ... );
```

or use the ProcessBuilder class.

You should be able to find example on the web that use these classes.

Edit: For example to start the Notepad exe in Windows you could do:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /C start notepad" );
```

If you want to execute a class then you need to invoke the JVM the same way you would invoke it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested looking into [executing an external process](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html).

This would require either [Runtime.getRuntime().exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) or the newer [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you would use Runtime.exec() or a ProcessBuilder similar to how you'd call an exe program if you weren't calling it from a GUI.  Some things to take care about are that you'd likely want to call the Runtime.exec() on a background thread off of the Swing main thread, the EDT, such as provided by a SwingWorker object.  Otherwise your GUI could freeze while the exe program takes over the Swing thread.  Also you'll also want to head all of the warnings about calling Runtime.exec() shown in this great article, 
[When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), possibly one of the best articles written on the subject --highly recommended!

Question: What do you mean by this statement as it isn't clear to me?:

> Note: The program.exe file is created from a java main program.

Comment: The note: I wrote a mainProgram class in java, and created the .exe file using that class. However, instead of using the .exe file, is it possible to use my JButton to launch a class (with the mainProgram)? If yes, what should I write for the actionListener?

Comment: My lord, yes, and in fact this is the greatly preferred way to call other Java code.  You could create a new object inside the action listener and call its methods.  Is this other class another Swing GUI?  If so, there are other considerations that may be important, and you may want to provide us with more detail.

Comment: No Jesus. The other class is also main program, but it has no GUI. So when I run the GUI class (which is also a main class) and i click the button, it will run the program from that other main class. The question is, what do i write in the actionListener line to call that other class?

Comment: @Mike, You've been given the classes to use. What examples did you find when you searched the web? What problems do you have understanding these examples? Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating what you have tried so we can see what your problems might be.

Comment: You can always call a main method as a static method of the class, but this smells of bad design, of breaking OOPs structure.  I agree with Rob Camick, you need to give us more and better information for us to be able to give you better answers, including creating and posting a small program, an SSCCE that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative answer without creating a new process through Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) - and you can maintain your System.in/out channels, too. However,
if you are new to the world of java programming and trying to learn the ropes, I would suggest following camickr's advice and not messing with the ClassLoader as described below.

I am assuming the class you need to run is self contained (uses no inner classes) and not already in your classpath or jarfile so you could just create an instance and call its main().
If there are multiple class files involved, just repeat the method for loading them.

So, in the ActionListener that your JButton addActionListener()-ed to ...

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    String classNameToRun = e.getActionCommand(); // Or however you want to get it
    try {
        new MyClassLoader().getInstance(classNameToRun).main (null);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Sorry, Cannot load class "+classNameToRun,
                            "Your title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}}
```

You will need a new class MyClassLoader already in your classpath. Here is a pseudocode:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;

public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

        protected       String classDirectory = "dirOfClassFiles" + File.separator,
                                packageName = "packageNameOfClass.";

        /**
         * Given a classname, get contents of the class file and return it as a byte array.
         */

        private byte[] getBytes (String className) throws IOException {
                byte[] classBytes = null;
                File file = new File (classDirectory + className + ".class");

                // Find out length of the file and assign memory
                // Deal with FileNotFoundException if it is not there
                long len = file.length();
                classBytes = new byte[(int) len];

                // Open the file
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream (file);

                // Read it into the array; if we don't get all, there's an error.
                // System.out.println ("Reading " + len + " bytes");
                int bCount = fin.read (classBytes);
                if (bCount != len)
                        throw new IOException ("Found "+bCount+" bytes, expecting "+len );

                // Don't forget to close the file!
                fin.close();
                // And finally return the file contents as an array
                return classBytes;
        }

        public Class loadClass (String className, boolean resolve)
                                                throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException,
                                                IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
                Class myClass = findLoadedClass (packageName + className);
                if (myClass != null)
                        return myClass;

                byte[] rawBytes = getBytes (className);
                myClass = defineClass (packageName + className,
                                                rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.length);
                // System.out.println ("Defined class " +packageName + className);
                if (myClass == null)
                        return myClass;
                if (resolve)
                        resolveClass (myClass);

                return myClass;
        }

        public Object getInstance (String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                try {
                        return loadClass (className, true).newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException inExp) {        inExp.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ilExp) {        ilExp.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioExp) {                   ioExp.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
        }
}
```

Notes:
This works well when the class you are trying to load is residing on your local machine and you are running java from the command line. I was never successful trying to get an applet to download a classfile from some servlet and load it - security will not allow that. In that case, the workaround is just to run another applet in another window, but that's another thread. The above classloading solves the problem of having to jar up every single classfile that you might be needing - just to start the GUI. Good luck, - M.S.